# TweetHighScore in iPhoneX iOS12 not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, twitter, iphone-x

Tweet in iOS12, iPhoneX not working.

```
-(void)TweetHighScore
{
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Testing"];
    [App.viewController presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

What's wrong in above code ?

Comment: Social.framework was deprecated in iOS 11 so I'm not surprised this does not work in iOS 12 either.

Comment: @AndyPiper thanks for your reply...Is there any alternative framework released by apple ?